# How to nest code block within a table cell using Markdown?

Tags: markdown

I'd like write some multiline code in markdown table cells like this

```
|pointers|`int a;` <br> `int *pa = &a;`||
```

I've to write `<br>` at each line of the codes, Whether I can do this, i.e., using code blocks?

````
|pointers|```c  int a; int *pa = &a; ```||
````

Comment: Which Markdown implementation are you using? [The original implementation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) doesn't support tables at all (unless you want to use HTML), and other implementations have varying levels of support for things like tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this efficiently/quickly. You could avoid using 
 however and format it like this :

```
| Pointers |
| -------- |
| `int a;` |
| `int *pa = &a;` |
| etc..  |
```

It does take more time, but I am aware that there is no alternate way to nest an entire code block. You can use the "```" method but it can only be single line.

Also generally make sure to have the |------| under the title of the table. It's also a good habit to get into indenting and spacing your code for clarity.